# Embed ROCKZify in website

Tags: php

First of all, hello to everyone and apologies for my poor English!

I want to embed a ROCKZify into my website but there has been an error.

```
Refused to display 'http://rockzi.com/rockzi/recipes?width=850&height=500&noheader=1&bg=259acd&btnbg=e62489&p=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsjapp%2F&pt=Home' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Please help me , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'`

The error message indicates that the browser has refused to display content in an iFrame because the content has specified that it should not be displayed in an iFrame of a different site.

Or

The page you want to display has a header that indicates it should not be displayed in an iFrame.

You can't fix this - it's set on the ROCKzify web site.